CKEditor5: Upcasting complex HTML structures (since structureToElement doesn't exist)
I'm updating an existing Drupal site which uses CKEditor4 to CKEditor5. What this means is that the stored data already contains various components as HTML, in various complex nested ways. Imagine we have a component like this, for example:
<div data-widget-dept="website" data-widget-type="contact">
    <div data-widget-content="description">description here</div>
    <div data-widget-content="address">
        <p>Address goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div data-widget-content="telephone">
        <p>Telephone number here</p>
    </div>
</div>

This doesn't seem to be easily handleable with the upcast helpers such as elementToElement, so I think I need to use the event-based API. However, this is very verbose! Looking at the converting structures examples from the documentation, it would require a whole load of very repetitive code to consume each of these sub-items, which makes for a very long and difficult-to-follow function: lots of "get the first child; is it a div; does it have data-widget-content==address; if so consume it; now convertChildren its children; now go on to the second child; etc etc etc". This seems laborious, especially when there are thirty or so of these components to do. Am I missing something about a better way to do this? Is there a better approach?
